# Modular square root of product of numbers

Tags: modular-arithmetic, radicals, gcd-and-lcm

Assuming $p>2$ is a prime, $d>a>1$ integers, and $gcd(p^a,b) = 1$, given that we know that an $x$ exists such that:

$\ x^2 = p^a*b\,(mod\;p^d)$

Does that mean that $p^a$ and $b$ both have to have square roots themselves? 
or can the product (only) have a square root?

Comment: Say, $p=3>2$, let $d=3>a=2>1$ and $b=2$. Then $\gcd(p^a,b)=\gcd(9,2)=1$ indeed, and $x^2=18\pmod{27}$. Now what is your $x$?

Comment: @IvanNeretin if I understood correctly, you mean to say that there **is no x** in your example; but I'm asking **assuming there is an x**, does that tell me anything about a or b?

Comment: Then you should have put it somewhat differently. As it stands now, your question seems to imply that such an $x$ always exists and we know that for sure.

Comment: Now to the point. Are you sure you didn't want to ask about $\mathbf p^a$ being a square $\pmod p^d$, rather than $a$? As it stands now, the answer is obviously negative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure enough, the answer is affirmative. Let's see why.

With $x^2=p^a\cdot b\pmod{p^d}$, our $x$ must be divisible by some power of $p$. But then its square is divisible by some *even* power of $p$, and hence $a$ must be even, which makes $p^a$ a square all right.

Now let $x=p^{a/2}\cdot c$. Then $p^a\cdot c^2=p^a\cdot b\pmod{p^d}$. So $c^2=b\pmod{p^{d-a}}$. In other words, $b$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p^{d-a}$, and by Hensel's lemma, also a quadratic residue modulo any higher power of $p$, including $p^d$.

Comment: Why must x "be divisible by some power of p"? I cannot find any counter-example, but I'm not sure how to prove this sentence

Comment: Well, we have $x^2=p^a\cdot b\pmod{p^d}$, which means $x^2=p^a\cdot b+p^d\cdot k$, so $x^2$ is divisible by $p^a$, so...